# Refresh Image after Source change

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an `Image`, and I'm changing its `Source`. Unfortunately the `Image` doesn't always update. My current workaround is:

```
theStackLayout.Children.Remove(image);
theStackLayout.Children.Insert(0, image);
```

There <s>must</s> should be a better way.

Comment: Try
theStackLayout.Children.Add(image);

Comment: You are doing it in the main thread right?